# Integration Tests with ZonedDateTime using Spring boot 1.4 error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, jhipster

I have my test cases failing for ZonedDateTime tests with an error. I am using [JHipster generator](https://jhipster.github.io/) 3.9.1

This is how dates to be used in tests are defined:

```
private static final ZonedDateTime DEFAULT_DATE = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(0L), ZoneId.systemDefault());
private static final String DEFAULT_DATE_STR = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.format(DEFAULT_DATE);
```

Then in test method:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void searchMeal() throws Exception {
    // Initialize the database
    mealService.save(meal);

    // Search the meal
    restMealMockMvc.perform(get("/api/_search/meals?query=id:" + meal.getId()))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].id").value(hasItem(meal.getId().intValue())))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].title").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_TITLE)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].description").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].picture").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_PICTURE)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].date").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_DATE_STR)));
}
```

Which gives the error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.[*].date"
Expected: a collection containing "1970-01-01T01:00:00+01:00"
 but: was "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
```

The test class definition uses Spring boot 1.4 annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = NutrilifeApp.class)
public class MealResourceIntTest {
```

What's the best/valid approach to test ZonedDateTime with Spring Boot?

Comment: If your REST API genuinely returns UTC, then also test for a UTC timestamp, and not the system default timezone (which is anyway bad, because it introduces a dependency to the system the test runs on, which means it can fail on one system and be successful on another).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation I decided to follow @dunni proposed solution above and changed the test data to use UTC, the code changed to this:

```
private static final ZonedDateTime DEFAULT_DATE = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(0L), ZoneOffset.UTC);
private static final String DEFAULT_DATE_STR = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(DEFAULT_DATE);
```

and the tests are now passing. For some reason the JHipster generator is adding tests for generated entities using system default timezone(ZoneId.systemDefault()), which cause tests using ZonedDateTime to fail.

Comment: Hi Marco,please consider opening an issue on jhipster github project and proposing a PR.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou - Sure, I will take a look there and do it.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou - Done it's here: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4373